# Jquery - Shrinking the DIV On click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the below code to animate the div.

```javascript
$("i.legend-icon").click(function(){
    $(".scatterchartcolumn").animate({width: '-=100px'});
});
```

1. I want the div, only to shrink. But it is completely hiding the div for 100px. I dont want that to happen.
2. I want the animation to stop and the div to go back to the same position as it was in default when I click on the same div again.

Here`s the code.. I want to stop it and make the .**scatterchartcolumn** to be in the same width when I click the i.legend-icon again as it was in default. Also I want the animation to run until I click the **i.legend-icon** again. Currently it stops animating in a second or so..

#### HTML

```html
<div class="scatterchartcolumn">
    <div id="scattercharty_axis"></div>
    <div id="scatterchart"></div>
    <div id="scatterchartx_axis"></div>
</div>
```

#### css

```css
.scatterchartcolumn {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 25px;
    width: 780px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: `$(".scatterchartcolumn").animate({width: '-100px'});`

Answer (score 2):

Below code will help you to do this

```
$(".legend-icon").click(function () {
       if ($(this).attr('id') == "icon1") {
          $(".scatterchartcolumn").animate({ width: '-=100px' }, 2500);
          $(this).attr('id', 'icon2');
       }
       else {
          $(".scatterchartcolumn").animate({ width: '+=100px' }, 2500);
          $(this).attr('id', 'icon1');
       }
   });
```

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuJuJ/) sample

Take a look at this [jqfaq.com](http://jqfaq.com/) site,it has more jquery related faqs. It may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "completely hiding the div for 100px", but as far as the toggle bit goes, you can do something like this:

```javascript
// cache the selector (don't search the DOM for .scatterchartcolumn on each click)
var col = $(".scatterchartcolumn"); 
var originalWidth = col.width(); // save the width
$("i.legend-icon").click(function(){
    if (col.hasClass("shrunk")) { // check for presence of "shrunk" class
        col.removeClass("shrunk") // toggle the class
            .stop(true, true) // clear the animation queue
            .animate({width: originalWidth});
    } else {
        col.addClass("shrunk")
            .stop(true, true)
            .animate({width: '-=100px'});
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DhpNQ/

As for your note: "I want the animation to run until I click the i.legend-icon again. Currently it stops animating in a second or so.." -- because it is a timed animation, the code is going to remove 100px off the width over a given period. (The jquery animation becomes impossible if we don't know when you're going to click the buttom). If you want to shrink it until you click the button you could make it shrink to 0px over a longer period perhaps? I am unsure what you really want.

---

#### update

In order to animate over a longer period, give a number (in ms) as the second argument to .animate() like this;

```
 .animate({width: 0}, 10000); // animate to 0 width over 10 000ms
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DhpNQ/1/

Comment: Hi bro!! Thanks for your answer. What I really want is.. Now with your code, when I click the  i.legend-icon, it shrinks, but only for particular time. So as u said its a timed animation. Can u pls guide me how can I change the shrink to 0px so that I can make the div to shrink until I click the same button again?

Comment: @Ash Updated the answer, is that what you wanted?

Comment: No Thats not Bro.. Sorry if I am not clear.. Click on i.legend-icon  -> div reduced to 100px width. Only if(click on,  i.legend-icon again) -> div go back to the originalWidth.

Comment: @Ash If you want it to set the width to 100px, just write 100px (without the -= business) http://jsfiddle.net/DhpNQ/2/

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kbCqe/)

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".scatterchartcolumn").click(function(){
  $(this).animate({
    width: "0px",
      height:"0px",
  }, 1500 );
});
    });
```